# Android M permission system: identify needs

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am in the process of migrating an app to Android M, and right now if I compile against SDK 23 I will get crashes here and there relating to permissions not being asked in the Marshmallow way (as in at the moment the user action actually requires those permissions).

The thing is, mine is a big app that has lots of obscure functionalities, so is there any way to properly identify sensitive points in the app where the permission prompt should be incorporated?

Comment: there are some lint checks that tell you but there are many places where nothing alerts you

Answer (score 0):

in android 6.0 appeared [runtime permission](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions)